# Having issues understanding views and view controllers inside a storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have issues understanding how the view inside the storyboard is targeted.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/27/uye0.jpg/

Here is an image of a storyboard containing 2 view objects (Correct me if I am wrong).

Now, I want to change the background color of one of the views, to my understanding I do this like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

If this is implemented in to the project that I linked above, this does nothing. The "viewDidLoad" never executes to my understanding.

The only view controller is named viewController, so my question is, how do I make viewControllers for both of the views? And how do I distinguish between the views when creating the view controllers?

And what identifier is used for this?

**EDIT 1**

I added

NSLog(@"Here") after viewDidLoad, and it does execute, but it never changes the background color of the view

Comment: Make sure that your storyboard knows to instantiate your "ViewController" class in order to manage the view controller you've defined in the storyboard.  Select your view controller in the storyboard.  In the right-hand pane in Xcode choose the "identity inspector" tab.  Under "Custom Class" enter the name of your view controller class (ie: "ViewController").  Rebuild.

Comment: How do i make sure it knows to instantiate my ViewController class? I only have a MainStoryboard.storyboard, in Outlets, the storyboard is linked with view1, the first view, and it does load just fine, i can swap between the views when i run it in the simulator. I just added NSlog(@"here") it does log it. But it does not change the color.

Comment: Thank you very much, i did as you said and i got it working after a few attempts, last question, how do i make a new viewController for another View? As in how do i target that view specificly ?

Comment: " storyboard containing 2 view objects" -- no, those are view controllers (with a view inside). To make another view controller, just drag one out from the library -- you can then add whatever you want to its view.

Comment: Added a reference for you to get started with Storyboard: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new objetive C class to contain the new view controller and then link that class to the other view in the storyboard:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHNvs.png